# Solr not returning results

Tags: search, solr

I am very new to Apache Solr and currently trying to understand the concepts. I am using version 6.3. I have created a schema and uploaded a file with a bunch of documents. I do see that 1388 documents are available.

When I put in the q field in the Admin UI "coursetitle:biztalk", I do get the relevant results back but not when I put "biztalk". I thought that I do not need to provide the field name?

Here is the schema:

```
<field name="courseid" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true" multiValued="false" />
<field name="coursetitle" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="false"/>
<field name="coursetitlesearch" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="false"/>
<field name="durationinseconds" type="int" indexed="true" stored="true" />
<field name="releasedate" type="date" indexed="true" stored="true"/>

<field name="description" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true"/>

<field name="assessmentstatus" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
<field name="iscourseretired" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
<field name="tag" type="string" multiValued="true" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
<field name="course-author" type="string" multiValued="true" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
```

Comment: is that the whole schema ?

Comment: In terms of my fields, yes

Answer (score 2):

You need to specify the field unless that you want to search it the default field.

when you do not specify any field solr search in the default Field which you can configure using the following in schema.

```
<defaultSearchField> coursetitle </defaultSearchField>
```

So if you put the above in schema.xml and then search for something like
`biztalk` in the query param, solr will search it as `coursetitle:biztalk`

if you want all your fields to be searched without having to specify a field name , look through `Copy Fields`

I recommend you to go through this https://wiki.apache.org/solr/SchemaXml to see various fields.

Comment: Thank you so much and sorry for relay in reply. Yes, you are right. defaultSearchField is depreated, though. So, I ended up adding the df to the resourcehandler and then of course, I had to use the copyField to make solr search through all fields. That being said, in my view, this solution is not ideal as it duplicates data. Ideally, each field should have an attribute like 'default-search=true', or the resourcehandler should have a setting in the defaults like <df>field-1,field-2,...</df>, don't you agree?

Answer (score 1):

Usually some important fields are copied to field which is used to search default by Solr. So I suggest you use same copyfield

Example:

```
<defaultSearchField>SEARCHINDEX</defaultSearchField>

 <copyField source="AUTHOR" dest="SEARCHINDEX"/>
 <copyField source="coursetitle" dest="SEARCHINDEX"/>
 <copyField source="coursetitlesearch" dest="SEARCHINDEX"/>
 <copyField source="SUBTITLE" dest="SEARCHINDEX"/>
```

Now You cane use SEARCHINDEX field to search all other fields content.
Since using `defaultSearchField` is depreciated, your request handler in solrconfig.xml defines `"df"`, which takes precedence.

```
<initParams path="/update/**,/query,/select,/tvrh,/elevate,/spell,/browse">
    <lst name="defaults">
      <str name="df">text</str>
    </lst>
  </initParams>
```

Comment: Thank you so much and sorry for relay in reply. Yes, you are right. defaultSearchField is depreated. So, I ended up adding the df to the resourcehandler and then of course, I had to use the copyField to make solr search through all fields. That being said, in my view, in solution is not ideal as it duplicates data. Ideally, each field should have a attribute like 'default-search=true', or the resourcehandler should have a setting in the defaults like <df>field-1,field-2,...</df>, don't you agree?

Answer (score 0):

After doing a little research, it looks like that by using edismax, we can indeed pass a list (space separated) of default fields in df e.g.:

```
df=courseid coursetitle course-author
```

This way, we do not need to use the copyField!

Comment: you are right. using query field qf paramter of dismax/edismax `qf=courseid coursetitle course-author` you can also boost your fields with different values. ex: `qf=courseid^2.0 coursetitle^10.0 course-author^3.0`